# how to convert NSData of image to CGImageRef with out memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, cgimageref

i converted NSData of image to CGImage as below but i am getting memory leaks there but any one tell me how to convert that with out getting leaks:

```
CFDataRef imgData;
CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider;
CGImageRef image1;
imgData = (CFDataRef)[array objectAtIndex:i];
    imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData (imgData);
    image1 = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
CFDataRef imgData;
CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider;
CGImageRef image1;
imgData = (CFDataRef)[array objectAtIndex:i];
imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData (imgData);
CFRelease(imgData);
image1 = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(imgDataProvider);
```

Don't forget to use `CGImageRelease(image1);` after you are done with it.

Comment: +1. @laxcha, read [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html). Core Graphics follows the Core Foundation memory management rules.